Separator unmatched kerberos 5 hash
I'm trying to use hashcat to decode a krb5 hash retrieved from a pcapng file in wireshark then hashcat keep saying separator unmatched.
Here's my hash:
$krb5$*CATCORP.LOCAL*william.dupond*168d462fef2c82289dbac48f37954672bc3d27737d960a36b22f0f5276a5a8d0838c34830458455072fdb4afb52671371a1d9d0904b417a5eddcdcf8caf66e8133cb27c6f6c217256f11983840828b328224201bf0e3a33cf5b6af807371b2d8557bcf3012d6902f46d3c116862bbdd03*

And then :
hashcat -m 18200 -a 0 -o cracked.txt hash.txt /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt
hashcat (v6.2.6) starting

OpenCL API (OpenCL 3.0 PoCL 3.1+debian  Linux, None+Asserts, RELOC, SPIR, LLVM 15.0.6, SLEEF, DISTRO, POCL_DEBUG) - Platform #1 [The pocl project]
==================================================================================================================================================
* Device #1: pthread-haswell-Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz, 2863/5791 MB (1024 MB allocatable), 8MCU

Minimum password length supported by kernel: 0
Maximum password length supported by kernel: 256

Hashfile 'hash.txt' on line 1 ($krb5$...7bcf3012d6902f46d3c116862bbdd03*): Separator unmatched
No hashes loaded.

Started: Wed Oct 23 17:54:39 2024
Stopped: Wed Oct 23 17:54:39 2024

I expected hashcat to start decoding the hash with the rockyou dictionary
